# How to execute a python function for every one hour exactly using apscheduler independent of program running start time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, apscheduler

I have a function, which is executed for every hour using `threading` module. But I have encountered problems with this,

i.e., the function is not running after couple of hours, like after 10 - 12 hours (This time is varying)

```
def update_df():
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connections['DB2'])
    threading.Timer(60*60*1, update_df).start()

update_df()
```

**Questions:**

1. What is best practice, to implement this function such that it
   should run for every IST hour(not on system time)?
2. Why `threading` module haven't worked properly (Is there any built-in module to do same job)?

**Edit-1:**

- Question-1 is sovled
- Question-2 need more visibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending the answer of @Harley,

You need to use `trigger='cron'` instead of `'interval'` to execute every hour

[Document](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron)

> **interval** : This should be used when you want to run a function after fixed number of hours/minutes/seconds irrespective of
>   day/month/year.
>
> **cron** : This should be used when you want to run a function at a particular day/month/year at a particular hour/minute/second.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone='Asia/Kolkata')
scheduler.add_job(method, trigger='cron', hour='*') # Execute every hour independent of execution time(i.e., 1:00:00, 2:00:00, so on..)
scheduler.add_job(method_1, 'interval', minutes=30) # Execute on every 30 minutes depends program execution time
scheduler.start()
```

To stop scheduler, use  `.remove_all_jobs()`

```
Ex: scheduler.remove_all_jobs()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use python apscheduler.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone='subcontinent/city')
scheduler.add_job(method-1, 'interval', seconds=10)
scheduler.add_job(method-2, 'interval', minutes=30)
scheduler.add_job(method-3, 'interval', hours=1)

//the below shceduler run mon-thu and sun on every o,15,30 and 45 minutes of each hour

scheduler.add_job(method, 'cron', minute='0,15,30,45', day_of_week='mon-thu,sun')
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain why `threading` module haven't worked properly and how this will resolve that issue?

Comment: Threads are basically use when you're using multiprocessing. if you have a single process to execute then we don't need to engage a thread. let the job done by "BackgroundScheduler".

Comment: I have two methods, one will run for every 10 seconds and another for every 1 hour. Can I use `scheduler1 = scheduler2 = BackgroundScheduler()`? Or is there any other way?